# Referencing non-ROS packages dependencies

Tags: roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to reference a non-ROS package through one of my ROS package but I not have found the correct option in the CMakeList to make this correctly. I want to include the .h of this non-ROS package on to my files, but i don't find the method to make visible.

Thanks in advance and sorry for this simple question, but I don't find any answer in the tutorials.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10640/referencing-non-ros-packages-dependencies/) by [mbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/265/mbj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You use the standard cmake directives, i.e.
`include_directories(dir...)` and `target_link_libraries(bin lib...)`.

Additionally it is good practice to make a rosdep entry in the manifest if the library is a system package, so that other users can install the dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're trying to use software already installed on your system @dornhege has the right answer.  If you're downloading and compiling the source inside your package you need to add the `include_directories(dir...)` and to expose the `.h` files upstream you need to add an export to your manifest for [cflags](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest/XML#export)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1